# Test-Bench For Full Adder in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module testbench_lab3 ();

    logic [2:0] a, b, s;
    logic c_out;
    logic [3:0] c;

    rc_adder4 UUT (
    
    );

    initial begin
        a = 0;
        forever begin
            #10 a++;
        end
    end

// COMPLETE BY WRITING AN INITIAL BLOCK FOR b. 
// Set initial value for b equal to 0 and increment b every 20 time units
    
    

    initial begin
        $display("TIME | A B | S CO");   
        $display("-----------------");    
        $monitor("  %2d | %d %d | %d %b", 
            $time, a, b, s, co);         

        #160;
        $finish();
    end

endmodule
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
This is my adder module:

```
module rc_adder_slice (
input logic a, b, c_in,
output logic s,c_out
);

    logic p, g;

    assign p = a ^ b;
    assign g = a & b;

    assign s = p ^c_in;
    assign c_out = (p & c_in)| g;

endmodule
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
This is my multi-bit adder module:

```
module rc_adder4 (
input logic[2:0]a, b,
output logic[2:0] s, 
output logic c_out
);

    logic [3:0] c;

    rc_adder_slice UUT[2:0] (
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .c_in(c[2:0]),
    .s(s),
    .c_out(c[3:1])

);



// COMPLETE USING ARRAY INSTANCING




    assign c[0] = 1'b0;// COMPLETE
    assign c_out = c[3];// COMPLETE
    
endmodule
```

I don't know how to write a test bench. I only have rc_adder4 UUT (
); and // COMPLETE BY WRITING AN INITIAL BLOCK FOR b.
// Set initial value for b equal to 0 and increment b every 20 time units these two parts left. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: the point of a testbench is to provide a sequence of values applied over time to the input signals of your device and then check if the output(s) behave correctly, e.g. inputs 1 and 3 of an adder should produce 4 as an output, and so on. You can use random values as well. Try it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You did not connect any ports to your UUT. Changing `rc_adder4 UUT ( );` to `rc_adder4 UUT ( .a(a), .b(b), .s(s), .c_out(c_out) );`

Also:

- `b` needs to be assigned in your test bench
- There is a `co` that should be `c_out`
- `c` in your test bench is not being used

Answer (score -1):

Made some changes to your code.

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module testbench_lab3 ();

logic [2:0] a, b, s;
logic c_out;
logic [3:0] c;

rc_adder_slice UUT[2:0] (
.a(a),
.b(b),
.c_in(c[2:0]),
.s(s),
.c_out(c[3:1])

  );

initial begin
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    forever begin
       // #10 a=$urandom; b=$urandom; c=$urandom; //Uncomment if want to use random values
       #10 ++a; ++b; ++c;
    end
end

// COMPLETE BY WRITING AN INITIAL BLOCK FOR b. 
// Set initial value for b equal to 0 and increment b every 20 time units

initial begin
    $display("TIME | A B | S CO");   
    $display("-----------------");    
    $monitor("  %2d | %d %d | %d %b", 
        $time, a, b, s, c_out);         

    #160;
    $finish();
end

endmodule
```